# How to decode html string

Tags: asp.net

I have This String:

```
<p>&nbsp;Item1</p><br><p>Item2</p>
```

I getting that from editor . I want Convert That to this :

```
Item1 Item2
```

How To can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the regular expression `&(.*);`

in C# this would look like

```
  string pattern = @"&(.*);";
  string replacement = "";
  string input = "<p>&nbsp;Item1</p><br><p>Item2</p>";
  string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
  Console.WriteLine(result);
```